# почему не отображаются картинки на сайте

Tags: php, html, html5, phpmyadmin

не отображаются картинки из бд mysql(там полностью прописан адрес фото)[image: (]

```
<?php 
    global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            do {
            echo '
            <li>
            <div class="block-images">
            <img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\swet\Сайтик\tovary\"'.$row["image"].'"/>
         </div>
         <p class="style-title"><a href="">' .$row["title"]. '</a></p>
         <a class="cart-style"></a>
         <p class="style-price"><strong></strong>руб.</p>
         <div class="description">'.$row["description"].'</div>
        </li>';
            }
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
        }

    ?>
```

[image: phpMyAdmin]

Comment: ну если в базе как вы говорите пути к картинкам прописаны, то может быть надо вместо этого `src="C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\swet\Сайтик\tovary\"'.$row["image"].'"` 
записать вот так: `src="'.$row["image"].'"` ?

Comment: возможно ли такое что из за названия самой папки на русском и картинок происходит такой результат?

Comment: вы просто сравните адреса картинок из базы с их реальными адресами.

Comment: первый ваш вариант не помог

Comment: Эдуард,реальный адрес это тоже самое расположение которое можно посмотреть в свойствах?если так то отпадает я копировала и вставляла значит расхождений быть не может

Answer (score 1):

У вас прописаны абсолютные пути к картинке в для файловой системы вашей ОС. Вам же нужно прописывать пути относительно ROOT-директории вашего веб-сервера. Например, если `localhost` смотрит в папку `C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\`, а картинки находятся в `C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\swet\Сайтик\tovary\`, то при выводе нужно прописывать

`<img src="/swet/Сайтик/tovary/blaba.jpg">`

или

`<img src="http://localhost/swet/Сайтик/tovary/blaba.jpg">`

Главное понять, что у вас является корневой директорией веб-сервера. Кстати, обратите внимание на слэши, они должны быть прямыми, если речь идёт про URI.

При этом, в самой базе желательно прописывать только относительный путь или вообще только имя файла, т.к. структура папок всегда можно поменяться. Например, в колонке `image` вы сохраняете просто **blaba.jpg**, а затем выводите:

`echo '<img src="http://localhost/swet/Сайтик/tovary/'.$row["image"].'">';`

И да, от кирилических символов точно нужно избавиться.

Comment: я сделала как вы говорите,полностью убрала кириллицу и в бд записала только название файла 
но результат такой же что и прежде

Comment: @Вика покажите по какому адресу вы заходите на сайт и какой адрес получается у картинок в исходном коде страницы (см. исходный код страницы в бразере).

Comment: ошибку показывает Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/dashboard/swet/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA/tovary/
в коде браузера

Comment: http://localhost/dashboard/swet/Site/ind.php

Comment: @Вика еще раз. У вас сейчас код вида `<img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\swet\Сайтик\tovary\"'.$row["image"].'"/>`. Поменяйте его на `<img src="http://localhost/dashboard/swet/Сайтик/tovary/"'.$row["image"].'"/>`. Вместо `Сайтик` поставьте что вы там поменяли вместо кириллицы. А вот в самой базе вместо полного пути должно быть только имя файла с картинкой. В итоге в браузере в html коде вы должны увидеть что-то вроде <img src="http://localhost/swet/Сайтик/tovary/blaba.jpg">. Если не получится, советую открыть любую статью и понять хотя бы самые основы.

Comment: ,это у меня в коде <img src="http://localhost/dashboard/swet/Site/tovary/" '.$row["image"].' "/>. В БД я  уже указала только имя файла.Но код что в браузере отображает старый адрес C:/xampp/htdocs/dashboard/swet/Site/tovary/
Вот это как изменить?

Comment: @Вика это очень странно. Возможно, где-то срабатывает кэш. Попробуйте поменять что-то другое и посмотреть, изменится ли код.